# Error - Invalid field 'Shares' for CustomObject__c

Tags: custom-object, dynamic-apex, sharerecord

Quick Dynamic apex question here. I have a list of generic SObjects and I'd like to dynamically get the child share records (I have queried for them previously):

```
for( SObject rec : records ){
    for( SObject share : (List<SObject>)(rec.get('Shares')) ){ .... }
}
```

This code compiles, but when I try to run it, I get the following error:

> System.SObjectException: Invalid field Shares for CustomObjectName__c

Where CustomObjectName__c is the name of my custom object.

I've used rec.get() before many times, but is it not supported for child share records?

I'm using the generic SObject approach, as I'm building a sharing utilities class for multiple types of SObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SObject.get(fieldName)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get) returns the value for the field specified by fieldName. `Shares` is the relationship name, it isn't a field of your custom object, that's why you got that error.

In a parent-to-child query, if you want to extract the child records you must use [`getSObjects(relationshipName)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getSObjects):

> This method is primarily used with dynamic DML to access values for associated objects, such as child relationships.

I.E.

```java
// This could be a dynamic query
List<Sobject> accounts = [SELECT Name, (SELECT Id FROM Shares) FROM Account];
for (Sobject acc : accounts) {
    for (Sobject share : acc.getSObjects('Shares')) {
        System.debug(share.get('Id'));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, apologies! I should have had more caffeine and read the documentation more thoroughly. Thank you for your time.